# "Path /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1695989787169/work for brotli does not exist" when running poetry

Tags: python, conda, python-poetry

I'm trying to setup a project. It's instruction says running "make setup". I ran into an error because it requires poetry. I installed poetry (conda install poetry), and run the setup again. I ran into the following error messages:

"Installing dependencies from lock file
Path /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1695989787169/work for brotli does not exist

Path /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1695989787169/work for brotli does not exist"

After reading the Makefile file, I realized that the error comes from running "poetry install --sync".

I edited the poetry.lock and deleting all the packages. The error message is gone. But as long as I have a "package = []" line, the error would appear.

Any idea?